# Calculate an integral

Tags: integral-transforms

For $x\in \mathbb R_+$, let us define
$$
I_\lambda(x)=\frac2π\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin t}{t\sqrt{1+t^2x^2}}\cos(\lambda \arctan (xt)) \,dt,\quad \lambda\in 1+2\mathbb N.
$$
We see that $I_\lambda(0)=1$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}I_\lambda(x)=0.$
My hunch is that
$$
\forall x>0,\quad I_\lambda(x)<1.\tag {$\ast$}
$$
I do not know if the assumption on $\lambda$ is important and I would like to know if $(\ast)$ holds true.

Comment: $I_1(x)=1-e^{-1/x}$

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker Thanks for this sharp calculation. With
$$
F_{k}(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{\sin x t}{\pi t}\frac{(1+it)^{2k+1}}{(1+t^{2})^{k+1}} dt,
$$ we get indeed $F_0(x)=1-e^{-x}$(your calculation), and also $F_1(x)=1-e^{-x}(1+2x)$, $F_2(x)=1-e^{-x}(1+2x^2)$, $F_3(x)=1-e^{-x}(1+2x-2x^2+4x^3/3),$ and a general formula involving the Laguerre polynomials.